# Where do I add a return true or false here

Tags: php

I'm using the code below to re-size images in php. Its inside a function. It executes if $imgSource is true. If something in this failed, I'd like it to return false (maybe imagecopyresampled failed or something else failed). Thing is, where do I put the return true or false statement. Right now it'll return false even if things went ok or not. Do I have to write if statements for all that's in there. Can u please suggest a good way to do this.

```
if ($imgSource)
{

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($thisImage);

$dispImageWidth=500;
$dispImageHeight=($height/$width)*$dispImageWidth;
$tempDisplayImage=imagecreatetruecolor($dispImageWidth,$dispImageHeight);

$thumbImageWidth=250;
$thumbImageHeight=($height/$width)*$thumbImageWidth;
$tempThumbImage=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight);

imagecopyresampled($tempDisplayImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$dispImageWidth,$dispImageHeight,$width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($tempThumbImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight,$width,$height);

$displayImageTarget = $thisPath.'disp_'.$fileName;
$thumbImageTarget = $thisPath.'thumb_'.$fileName;

imagejpeg($tempDisplayImage,$displayImageTarget,100);
imagejpeg($tempThumbImage,$thumbImageTarget,100);

imagedestroy($imgSource);
imagedestroy($tempDisplayImage);
imagedestroy($tempThumbImage);
unlink($thisImage); 

//Where do I put the return true or false?

}
```

Comment: Wrap it in a try catch, at the end of the try add return true, in the catch, return false. That is dependant on gd functions throwing exceptions on error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some thing like `if(! your statement ) return false;`

**CODE**
    if ($imgSource)
    {

```
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($thisImage);

$dispImageWidth=500;
$dispImageHeight=($height/$width)*$dispImageWidth;
$tempDisplayImage=imagecreatetruecolor($dispImageWidth,$dispImageHeight);

$thumbImageWidth=250;
$thumbImageHeight=($height/$width)*$thumbImageWidth;
$tempThumbImage=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight);

if(! imagecopyresampled($tempDisplayImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$dispImageWidth,$dispImageHeight,$width,$height)) return false;
if(! imagecopyresampled($tempThumbImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight,$width,$height)) return false;

$displayImageTarget = $thisPath.'disp_'.$fileName;
$thumbImageTarget = $thisPath.'thumb_'.$fileName;

if(!imagejpeg($tempDisplayImage,$displayImageTarget,100)) return false;
if(!imagejpeg($tempThumbImage,$thumbImageTarget,100)) return false;

if(!imagedestroy($imgSource)) return false;
if(!imagedestroy($tempDisplayImage)) return false;
if(!imagedestroy($tempThumbImage)) return false;
if(!unlink($thisImage)) return false;

return true;


}
```

if you only want to check the unset

just do `return unlink($thisImage);`

**unlink Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.** see the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: Not sure this really answers the OP question?

Comment: @JonStirling: Sorry I misunderstood the Que

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Try catch' to return false when something fails.

```
if ($imgSource)
{

try

{


 list($width,$height)=getimagesize($thisImage);

 $dispImageWidth=500;
 $dispImageHeight=($height/$width)*$dispImageWidth;
 $tempDisplayImage=imagecreatetruecolor($dispImageWidth,$dispImageHeight);

 $thumbImageWidth=250;
 $thumbImageHeight=($height/$width)*$thumbImageWidth;
 $tempThumbImage=imagecreatetruecolor($thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight);

 imagecopyresampled($tempDisplayImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$dispImageWidth,$dispImageHeight,$width,$height);
 imagecopyresampled($tempThumbImage,$imgSource,0,0,0,0,$thumbImageWidth,$thumbImageHeight,$width,$height);

 $displayImageTarget = $thisPath.'disp_'.$fileName;
 $thumbImageTarget = $thisPath.'thumb_'.$fileName;

 imagejpeg($tempDisplayImage,$displayImageTarget,100);
 imagejpeg($tempThumbImage,$thumbImageTarget,100);

 imagedestroy($imgSource);
 imagedestroy($tempDisplayImage);
 imagedestroy($tempThumbImage);
 unlink($thisImage); 

 return true;

}

catch(Exception $e)

{


  return false;

}
//Where do I put the return true or false?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the image functions return true or false depending on success or failure, so you can do something like:

```
if(imagejpeg($tempDisplayImage,$displayImageTarget,100)==false){
    return false;
}
```

For every image function you use that supports it.

And then add return true; at the end of your function.